# Python reading and writing a csv file working with dates

Tags: python, csv, datetime, calendar

I would like to see in python, the code that reads a csv file containing  years of historical dates with a value (example of each line: 2016-09-23,2173.290039) , this code would then write another csv file with every date and its associated value that occurs on a Friday.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you show us your current code? Or do you want someone to write code for you?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow  user3597951 !!! This site is for asking question regarding code. No one is going to write code for you here. Please share you code and error if any. Please go through this link -    http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @WilliamFernandes - OP wants code . Check this line - "I would like to see in python, the code that reads"

Comment: @user3597951 - If you are new to Python, please try to Google it. Check this link for results - https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN584IN584&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Python+reading+and+writing+a+csv+file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will do what you need:

```
from datetime import datetime   
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        if datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d").weekday() == 4:       # if Friday
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

If `input.csv` contains:

```
2016-09-23,2173.290039
2016-09-24,2174.290039
2016-09-25,2175.290039
2016-09-26,2176.290039
```

It will create `output.csv` containing:

```
2016-09-23,2173.290039
```

Comment: Martin, that works perfectly. I took fortran in college many years ago. ...I'm having fun trying to learn this now for a specific little project.  This was the encouragement I needed !

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to click on the grey tick by the answer to accept it as the solution.